# Computed properties in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, vue.js, computed-properties

What is the best way to do the same as computed properties in vue ( https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html ) or reactive declarations in svelte ( https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations ) in react native?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `useMemo` hook. Docs for `useMemo` hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo